# Serilog best aproach for outputing to file and elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, .net-core, serilog

I used to ship my data to Elasticsearch by FileBeat-LogStash pipeline. Processed my logs which was created via log4net, mutated them, and sent required fields towards elastic.
Now I would like to replace my logic by removing the FileBeat and Logstash and make use of Serilog and it's [elasticsearch sink](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-elasticsearch).
To broader the picture I have an API endpoint which receives requests which I need to log to a textual file as they are so I need a `File` sink. Further down the code, my business logic will make use of data received and among else create an object which I then need to ingest to an index at elastic.
What's the best approach for this, have one Serilog instance and use some kind of filtering or have two Serilog instances? I'm closer to decorating (enrich) my cases and then using sinks by filtering (one Serilog instance) but because I'm a novice with Serilog I don't know how to set up the whole thing.

The abbreviated code would be something like this,
My controller class:

```
public class RequestController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly BLService _service = new BLService(Log.Logger);

    [Route("Test")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Test([FromBody]SampleRequest request)
    {
        var logId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        using (LogContext.PushProperty("LogId", logId))
            Log.Information("{@request}", request);

        var tran = new SampleTran
        {
            SampleTranType = "Test",
            SampleTranId = request.Id,
            EventTime = DateTime.Now
        };

        _service.ProcessTransaction(tran);

        return new OkResult();
    }
}
```

And my service where I'm adding property `"Type"` with constant value `"ElkData"` which I could then filter on:

```
public class BLService
{
    private readonly ILogger _log;

    public BLService(ILogger logger)
    {
        _log = logger.ForContext("Type", "ElkData");
    }

    public void ProcessTransaction(SampleTran transaction)
    {
        var elkData = DoSomeStuffAndReturnElkTransactionToStore(transaction);
        _log.Information("{@ElkData}", elkData );
    }
}
```

One note, my text file should only contain raw requests (without elasticsearch data). So far I'm writing all to file, and my `appsettings.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "C:\\DEV\\Logs\\mylog-.txt",
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u3}] {Message:j}{NewLine}{Exception}"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext" ]
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

I need to add the elastic part using filtering, am I right? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I managed to do what I need:
I've used `ForContext` to enrich my log items. So in the controller, I used:

```
var requestLog = Log.ForContext("Type", "Request");
requestLog.Information("Request: {@request}", request);//this needs to go to the log file
```

the code in BLservice stays the same and the filtering is described in the `appsettings.json` as:

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Logger",
        "Args": {
          "configureLogger": {
            "Filter": [
              {
                "Name": "ByExcluding",
                "Args": {
                  "expression": "Type = 'ElkData'"
                }
              }
            ],
            "WriteTo": [
              {
                "Name": "File",
                "Args": {
                  "path": "C:\\DEV\\Logs\\mylog-.txt",
                  "rollingInterval": "Day",
                  "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u3}] {Message:j}{NewLine}{Exception}",
                  "shared": true
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Logger",
        "Args": {
          "configureLogger": {
            "Filter": [
              {
                "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
                "Args": {
                  "expression": "Type = 'ElkData'"
                }
              }
            ],
            "WriteTo": [
              {
                "Name": "Elasticsearch",
                "Args": {
                  "nodeUris": "<your elastic url>",
                  "TypeName": "_doc",
                  "IndexFormat": "serilog_data",
                  "InlineFields":  true,
                  "BufferBaseFilename": "C:\\DEV\\Logs\\elk_buffer"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So the file will contain everything that is logged out except logs that carry `"Type = 'ElkData'"` enrichment, those will end up in elasticsearch index.

Hope this simple approach will help some serilog novice out there someday